# missing packge ,how to find the correct package

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While running cmake the following package missing problem occured ,
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "sys" with any of
the following names:

```
sysConfig.cmake
sys-config.cmake
```

How to solve this

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255304/missing-packge-,how-to-find-the-correct-package/) by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2017-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you by any chance trying to `find_package(..)` the `sys` module from Python in your `CMakeLists.txt`?

If so, that is not needed and won't work: apart from the fact that `sys` is part of the Python standard runtime libs, Python modules are never `find_package(..)`ed.

Just remove it from your `CMakeLists.txt`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0